# Increase convergence of non-linear equations resulting from ODEs

Tags: matrix, ode, iterative-method, convergence, newton-method

I am trying to solve a set of couple ODEs:

$V_l(r) - r W_l(r) -  f1(r) W_l'  = 0\tag 1$

$r^2 h''_l(r) + f2 r h_l'(r) + f3 h_l(r) - f4 U_l(r) = 0 \tag 2$

$\kappa (U_l + h_l) + V_{l+1} + W_{l+1}  = 0\tag 3$

$\kappa (U_{l-2} + h_{l-2}) + f5V_l' + f6W_l' + f7 U'_{l-1} +f8U'_{l-2} = 0 \tag 4$

for $V_l,W_l,h_l,U_l$ and $\kappa$. These functions and the $fn$ are only functions of $r$. Note: These are not the actual ODEs, just a representation of them. There are actually not 4 equations, but $4*l$, where $l$ is the one that appears in the spherical harmonics $Y^l_m$, and $l$ must start at $l=2$.  Also I know what the $fn$ functions are, I do not need to solve for them.

The method I have used to solve this is a spectral approximation. I take know and unknown functions in the ODEs and expand them in Chebyshev polynomials, for example

$f1(r) = \Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}f1_i T_i[y] - \frac{1}{2} f1_0 $

and

$U_2 = \Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}U_{2_i} T_i[y] - \frac{1}{2} U_{2_0} $

Applying this to equation (2) I get something like:

$[\kappa * (U_{2_N} + h_{2_N}) + V_{3_N} + W_{3_N} ]*T_N + \ldots - 1/2[\kappa * (U_{2_0} + h_{2_0}) + V_{3_0} + W_{3_0} ]*T_0  $

where $N$ is the maximum order of the Chebyshev polynomial. So if I extract the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomials I get $4*l*N$, non-linear equations. I say nonlinear because there will be terms like $\kappa * U_{2_N}$, etc. From now on I will refer to the vector of $U_{2_N}, h_{2_N}, \ldots$ as $X$.

In order to solve this non-linear set of equations I am first using the condition that the matrix of equations, $a(\kappa,X)$ needs to satisfy $det(a) = 0$. To makes use of this I am using a singular value decomposition (SVD) to find a $\kappa$ that makes $a$ as singular as possible. To get the values for $X$ I make a new matrix $a'$ in which I remove a row from $a$ and replace it with a "normalization" condition

$\Sigma U_{2_i} T_i = 1$

and then do LinearSolve[a',B]. All the elements of B are zero, expect the one that corresponds to the row that I delete, that element of B is 1.

**The main issue I am having is that my value for $\kappa$ does not converge very well. That is, when I increase $l$ and increase $N$ I would expect to get one value of $\kappa$, however at best I can get about 4 digits of convergence, but no matter what I try to do the fifth digit is just random**

I've tried messing with the physical model, and trying to increase the accuracy of the calculations, but nothing seems to help. The matrix is poorly conditioned: 1^8 to 1^10. And so I'm sure this is causing some issues.

**My attempts at a solution**
1st Attempt:

I've tried  to implement a Newton-Raphson method to try and fix the convergence. What I do is start with the matrix $a$, and treat $\kappa$ as a variable like one of the variables in $X$. Then I create the Jacobian

$J = \frac{\partial A_i }{\partial x_j}$
where $A_i$ represents an element of a vector that is made from the rows of my matrix $a$ with the additional equation that comes from the "normalization" condition. I include this so that I have $4*l*N +1 $ equations since now I'm trying so solve for $\kappa$ and $X$ all at once. And $x_j$ has all the elements of $X$ and $\kappa$.

Then I use the values of $\kappa$ and $X$ I got from doing the SVD and row replacement stuff above to use as the initial guess for the Newton's method, and then do

$z = LinearSolve[J, -A]$, and I take $z$ and add it to guess $X$, and repeat. However there is no convergence, in fact the the vector $X$ goes to zero like I'm stuck at the root, basically the $z$ I get is just $-X$. I tried giving LinearSolve the Krylov option, and there the $z$ that I get just flies off to infinity.

I'm not sure where the problem is. I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that my Jacobian might be close to singular ($det (J) \approx.00001$). I read some other stackexchange forums that said to use a QR decomposition instead of LinearSolve, and I tried that and got no convergence there either.

2nd Attempt: 
I tried using a QR algorithm for finding eigenvalues on matrix $a(\kappa,X)$. The idea is that I will look for the value of $\kappa$ which give me an eigenvalue as close to zero as possible. Again, this method does not do any better than the SVD stuff I was already using.

Long, long, story short, I really need some help, figuring out just how to make this result converge better. I would want something like 10 digits, but seriously 6 or 7 would be a miracle. What's more I don't care how slow the code gets, if it works it works.

**1st Edit**
The functions are defined on the domain ($0,R$), where physically zero is the center of a sphere and $R$ is the radius.

The boundary conditions are:
$W_l(r = R) = 0$
$h_{in}(r=R) = h_{out}(r=R)$

and 
$h_{l_{out}(r)} = constant*(R/r)^l$

and
$h_l \rightarrow (r/R)^{l+1}$ as $r \rightarrow 0$

$U_l \rightarrow (r/R)^{l+1}$ as $r \rightarrow 0$

$V_l \rightarrow (r/R)^l$ as $r \rightarrow 0$

$W_l \rightarrow (r/R)^l$ as $r \rightarrow 0$

Comment: I see now that you have a boundary value problem.  Have you tried just handing your problem to a standard BVP solver in MATLAB, Mathematica, or Maple?

Comment: I don't think I've ever really tried that, because of the nature of the boundary conditions. Not really sure how to give Mathematica something like $h''_l + h'_l +\ldots = 0$ given $h_l(r=0) \rightarrow (r/R)^3$. Also there is the issue of the parameter $\kappa$. I would have to guess a value and solve the ODEs and somehow keep guessing until things converged. Not sure how to do this either? Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $h_l(r=0)\to(r/R)^3$.  Shouldn't that just be $h_l(r=0)\to0$?  And I don't understand where the other condition comes from in your description.  Anyway, I suggest re-writing your question with the whole problem statement at the top and an explanation of why you haven't used a standard method.